# Load Testing Crash Course

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance

Can someone point me at a good resource to get a crash course in load testing?

I have a SQL Server machine that I need to load test but I haven't been thruogh the process before. We do not have any third party software for this, or money to purchase any, so that option would be out.

Comment: If you haven't done this before then the best thing you can do is to hire someone who has been there, done that and has the battle scars to prove it. Just to become familiar with the complexity that can go into a performance test you should take a look at the industry documentation for the defacto performance benchmark for databases, TPC-C [PDF Documentation on the TCP-C Database Benchmark](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/spec/tpcc_current.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an excellent post from Kendra Little regarding this.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/06/load-test-sqlserver/

There are several tools out there, both commercial and free. In past when I had need I used
Adam Machanic's [SQLQueryStress](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/)

[SQL Load Generator](http://sqlloadgenerator.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex is another free tool you can use also.